# GAE Datastore: Multitenancy for organization

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

We are now developing an application that uses GAE Datastore and trying to implement [Multitenancy](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/multitenancy/multitenancy#Go_Avoiding_data_leaks).
Our customers are companies, so we are going to create namespaces on a per-company basis.

My question is how should we treat company mergers and separations.

For example, when two of our customers are merged, data under two namespaces should be migrated into a single namespace. When our customer is separated into two company, some of data should be migrated into another namespace. This takes a lot of effort and we would like to avoid these operations.

How can we treat these cases smoothly? Or is namespace suitable for per-company basis? If not, how should we implement per-company based multitenancy?

Answer (score 0):

The general way this is handled is by creating a job that handles mergers as a batch process by read-write-delete the old to new keys as part of a transaction. Generally you'll have a bunch of business rules you throw in as part of the processing as well as the basic rekeying. For example, how will you handle 2 users having the same username?

Using Cloud Dataflow (Java & Python connectors available) is a good tool to do this.

Mergers are messy when it comes to data in most cases, so it isn't really namespaces that prevent a simpler solution.